# Trigger action in a particular element of a collection inside an ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects that is displayed using ng-repeat. In each of these objects there's a button that triggers an API request and toggles a flag in order to show a hidden div. Here's the HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="tarjeta in tarjetas">
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="card" checked>  {{tarjeta.brand}} ************{{tarjeta.digits}}  
    <button class="btn btn-dropdown" ng-click="openEditCard(); getEditableInfoCard(tarjeta.id)" ng-show="!editCard"></button>
    <button class="btn btn-up" ng-click="openEditCard()" ng-show="editCard"></button>
</label> 
<div ng-show="editCard">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre en la tarjeta:" class="form-control" ng-model="editableInfo.name" required>
    <p ng-show="validaUpdateName">Dato incorrecto</p>
    <div style="float: left; margin-right: 15px;">
        <input type="text" name="expM" placeholder="Expiración (MM):" maxlength="2" class="form-control" ng-model="editableInfo.exp_month" required>
        <p ng-show="validaUpdateMM">Dato incorrecto</p>
    </div>
    <label class="dash">
        /
    </label>
    <div style="float: left;">
        <input type="text" name="expY" placeholder="Expiración (YYYY):" maxlength="2" class="form-control" ng-model="editableInfo.exp_year" required>
        <p ng-show="validaUpdateYY">Dato incorrecto</p>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="direccion" placeholder="Dirección de la tarjeta:" class="form-control" required>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div style="float: right;">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateCard(tarjeta)">Guardar cambios</button>
        <button class="btn btn-trash"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I click the button on a single element, the action is triggered for every element of the array. I think this is quite simple to solve but I'm a beginner using Angular and can't figure out what the problem is. I already tried tracking by $index. This is driving me crazy any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really hasn't much to do with angular. Only with logic.

You're using  single boolean `editCard`, and based on that boolean, you're supposed to know which cards should be opened, and which ones should not be. That can't possibly work. A single boolean can't store that amount of information. Only true or false.

Instead, you need, **for each card** to know if it is opened or not. So **each card** should have its own boolean flag:

```
<div ng-repeat="tarjeta in tarjetas">
    <button ng-click="tarjeta.edited = true" ...></button>
    <button ng-click="tarjeta.edited = false" ...></button>

    <div ng-if="tarjeta.edited">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And if only one card is supposed to be opened at a time, thenwhat you need to know is which of the card is opened. Again, a boolean can't store that information. So you'd need

```
<div ng-repeat="tarjeta in tarjetas">
    <button ng-click="edit(tarjeta)" ...></button>
    <button ng-click="edit(null)" ...></button>

    <div ng-if="tarjeta === editedTarjeta">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.editedTarjeta = null;
$scope.edit = function(tarjeta) {
    $scope.editedTarjeta = tarjeta;
};
```